# Comparing text file content

Tags: python

I have written a small script to compare a text files content to another text file containing a word list, however running it says that the matches cannot be found, I cannot fix the code to successfully compare them with correct results.

```
wordlist = input("What is your word list called?")
f = open(wordlist)
t = f.readlines()
l = ''.join(t).lower()
chatlog = input("What is your chat log called?")
with open(chatlog) as f:
   found = False
   for line in f:
       line = line.lower()
       if l in line:
          print(line)
          found = True
   if not found:
      print("not here")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wordlist = input("What is your word list called?")
f = open(wordlist)
l = set(w.strip().lower() for w in f)
chatlog = input("What is your chat log called?")
with open(chatlog) as f:
   found = False
   for line in f:
       line = line.lower()
       if any(w in line for w in l):
          print(line)
          found = True
   if not found:
      print("not here")
```